# How to group an array of objects by value for the same item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, api

I have a question, how can I map and reduce an array like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        Price: 50,
        Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
        Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        Price: 100,
        Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
        Date: {id: 2, Start: "202002"}
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        Price: 200,
        Item: {id: 2, Name: "B"},
        Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
    }
]
```

I'm writing an app in React and I want to show those values grouped in a table.

It should look something like this:

| ITEM | 202001 | 202002 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50 | 100 |
| B | - | 200 |

I would like to be able to do this with the array:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
        Date: [{id: 1, Start: "202001",Price: "50"},{id: 2, Start: "202002",Price: "100"}]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        Item: {id: 2, Name: "B"},
        Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001",Price: "200"}
    }
]
```

Any suggestions to get to what I need?

Comment: what the output you want to get in the end?

Comment: I inserted the table in Markdown format so you can see the result I want

Comment: Please see this post. It has almost same question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/9515661

Comment: Tried the following, but it doesn't group: `const tempData = [
  {
   id: 1,
   Price: 50,
   Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
   Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   Price: 100,
   Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
   Date: {id: 2, Start: "202002"}
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   Price: 200,
   Item: {id: 2, Name: "B"},
   Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
  }
 ]

 var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
   };

 console.log(groupBy(tempData, 'Item.Name'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` and then use `Object.values` like so:

```js
const arr = [
  {
      id: 1,
      Price: 50,
      Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
      Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      Price: 100,
      Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
      Date: {id: 2, Start: "202002"}
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      Price: 200,
      Item: {id: 2, Name: "B"},
      Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
  }
]

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {Item, Date, Price}) => {
  if(!acc[Item.id]) {
    acc[Item.id] = {
      id: Item.id,
      Item,
      Date: [{...Date, Price}]
    };
  } else {
    acc[Item.id].Date = [...acc[Item.id].Date, {...Date, Price}];
  }
    
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll test it by creating the table and then I'll tell you how it turned out.

Comment: I wanted to order the array this way, to map the data easier. What is the best way to loop through it and display the values as they are in the table?

Comment: @bonnegnu `map()` is fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupBy` method of `lodash` to group your dataset according to `Item.Name`.

First get the package:

```js
npm i lodash.groupby
```

Then use it in your code as

```js
import groupBy from 'lodash.groupby'

const tempData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        Price: 50,
        Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
        Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        Price: 100,
        Item: {id: 1, Name: "A"},
        Date: {id: 2, Start: "202002"}
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        Price: 200,
        Item: {id: 2, Name: "B"},
        Date: {id: 1, Start: "202001"}
    }
]

groupBy(tempData, 'Item.Name')

/*
Will result as below

{
    A: [
           //objects with 'Item.Name' === 'A'
       ],
    B: [
            //objects with 'Item.Name' === 'B'
       ]
}
*/
```

Then, you need to populate your table with the keys inside the response from `groupBy`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get this error ./node_modules/lodash.groupby/index.js - Module not found after installing lodash.groupby and running the app.